# Trying to plot multiple datasets: Getting "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, spyder

Python version is 3.9.5

Trying to run this in order to plot multiple datasets:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('data/inflammation*.csv'))
filenames = filenames[0:3]
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    
    data = np.loadtxt(fname = filename, delimiter = ",")
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20.0, 6.0))
    fig.suptitle(filename)
    
    axis1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
    axis2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
    axis3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
    
    axis1.set_xlabel('patient')
    axis1.set_ylabel('avg inflammation')
    axis1.plot(np.mean(data, axis = 0))
    
    axis2.set_xlabel('patient')
    axis2.set_ylabel('max inflammation')
    axis2.plot(np.max(data, axis = 0))
    
    axis3.set_xlabel('patient')
    axis3.set_ylabel('min inflammation')
    axis3.plot(np.min(data, axis = 0))
    
    fig.tight_layout()
    
    plt.show()
```

Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-fd43e0002bc9>", line 4, in <module>
    numpy.loadtxt(fname='data/inflammation-01.csv', delimiter = ",")

  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1096, in loadtxt
    first_line = next(fh)

  File "codecs.pyc", line 322, in decode

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It was working fine, then all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore and gives me that error....

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt` has a parameter named `encoding`. Try to set it to `utf-8`, or if that doesn't work, to other encodings which could apply to the dataset. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: Did not work... tried `utf-8` and `latin1` (just to try it).  Tbh I'm new to this, so I don't even know where to start in my research for the answer...

Comment: I figured out the issue.  Turns out, my "inflammation_01.csv" file was corrupted (was just showing wingdings or something when I opened up the file.  All the rest of the files of the same naming convention were fine.  Thanks for suggestion, definitely wil keep in my toolbox for troubleshooting later issues (which will definitely happen while I'm learning this haha.